# Implicit property animations do not work with CAReplicatorLayer?

Tags: ios, macos, core-animation

The sample code is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ReplicatorDemo/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html).

After replacing explicit property animations with implicit property animations, the animation is broken.

Explicit animation:

```
-(void)animate:(id)sender {
    ...
    //Transform Animation
    animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D: CATransform3DIdentity];
    animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D: t];
    animation.duration = 1.0;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
    [subLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transform"];

    //Opacity Animation
    animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    animation.duration = 1.0;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
    [subLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"opacity"];
    ...
}

-(void)reset:(id)sender {       
    ...
    //Transform Animation
    animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D: t];
    animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D: CATransform3DIdentity];
    animation.duration = 1.0;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
    [subLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transform"];

    //Opacity Animation
    animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    animation.duration = 1.0;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
    [subLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"opacity"];

    ...
}
```

Implicit animation:

```
-(void)animate:(id)sender {
    ...
    //Transform Animation
    [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:1];
    subLayer.transform = t;

    //Opacity Animation
    [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:1];
    subLayer.opacity = 0;
    ...
}

-(void)reset:(id)sender {       
    ...
    //Transform Animation
    [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:1];
    subLayer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;

    //Opacity Animation
    [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:1];
    subLayer.opacity = 1;       
    ...
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

u don't need to use CATrasaction when you use implicit animation.
be carefull that uikit disables the implicit animation of layer which is a root layer of UIView

Comment: [CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.0f]
                 forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];
theLayer.zPosition=200.0;
theLayer.opacity=0.0;
[CATransaction commit];

Answer (score -2):

You should to set CALayer's delegate to something different that view controllers view at an appropriate time (none of nitWithNibName:bundle:, awakeFromNib, viewDidLoad, and viewWillAppear:animated), look here: [Does iPhone OS support implicit animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176069/does-iphone-os-support-implicit-animation) .

On my machine calling animate on a touch worked very nicely.

Comment: Obviously, I'm using implicit transactions.

Comment: Obviously, I was wrong, did find a hint but couldn't test b/c of no OSX at hand. Obviously, you don't know the answer b/c you otherwise wouldn't ask. Now I've researched a bit more and found an answer that worked on my machine.

Comment: BTW CATransaction begin/commit don't make an animation explicit, as long as you won't create an animation and add it to the layer it still is an implicit animation. Obviously, I should add :-)