# Implicit Animation not Working on iPhone

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I have come across the following thread which sorted out part of my problem. (I tried to raise my question there but it seems its better putting it in a new thread).

[Does iPhone OS support implicit animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176069/does-iphone-os-support-implicit-animation/7133039#7133039)

The other part of my problem is the following

The approach recommended by justinkmunger in the thread above works fine for me:

```
CALayer *labelLayer = self.label.layer;
labelLayer.delegate = self;
layer.position = CGPointMake(labelLayer.position.x, labelLayer.position.y + 50);
```

However, I have two questions here:

1) how would i apply this approach to a CALayer object that is a sublayer of a UIView layer object, like in the following:

```
CALayer* l = [CALayer layer];
l.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 350);
layer.opacity = 0;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:l];

l.delegate = self;
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:5];
1.opacity = 1;    // DOES NOT ANIMATE!! Event if i add: self.view.layer.delegate = self;
```

2) Why this approach is not applicable to the layer in my UIViewController's view?

```
CALayer *layer = self.view.layer;
layer.delegate = self;
layer.opacity = 0;
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:5];
layer.opacity = 1;   // DOES NOT ANIMATE!!
Many thanks AF
```

Hope someone can help
Cheers
AF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some more search i came across the following on [Core Animation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Transactions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006096-SW1):

> Important: When modifying layer properties from threads that don’t have a runloop, you must use explicit transactions.

I am trying to activate the animation of the layers from Button clicks. Not sure if those are triggered on a separate thread and causing the fail of animating. Just thought of sharing this finding in case some else finds it useful.

Answer (score -2):

don't you need `[CATransaction begin];` and `[CATransaction commit];`

Comment: I am trying to do implicit animation and i believe with that you do not need to do begin/commit

Comment: Guesswork is really best suited in comments to the question, not as answers. Verify before you answer the question